# Is it possible to install the Japanese Language IME on Windows XP without a CD?

Tags: windows-xp, language-pack

I need to install Japanese language support; however every time I attempt to do so it prompts me to insert the Windows install CD?

I have an ASUS Eee 901 PC which came pre-installed with Windows XP SP3.  There was no install media included and there is no CD drive in the PC.  I cannot find any windows install media on the hard disk.

Is there any way to install Japanese language support online through windows update?

This is a legal and validated copy of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the [Office XP language pack for Windows 2000](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=24a66277-cd9f-4332-a6f1-52b85a6470bd&displaylang=en) installed correctly and provided the correct support without requesting anything from the original install media.

The file isn't recommended for Windows XP, but it worked for me.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for torrents for the language pack, and when you are prompted, just browse to the file.
Although I'm not sure where is a good place to find safe torrents.

Comment: Unless I could find a trusted source of the MD5 checksums of the official language pack file I would be very wary of installing anything from a torrent.